# hasClass is not working on mouse hover

Tags: jquery

Hello I am trying to find that class "toggle-nav" contains "dropdown" or not , but hasClass is not working.

My code is here:

```
<li class="toggle-nav">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Add User</a></li>
        <li><a href="#>">User List</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="toggle-nav">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Add Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#>">Admin List</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="toggle-nav1"><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggle-nav").hover(function() {
            console.log($(this).hasClass("dropdown"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please take the time to make your code human readable before you post it. You are far more likely to get quick and accurate help when you do

Comment: I would expect the console to show `false` in your example. Is that not what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because class dropdown exists in child element and not targeted element. You need to look for class in child elements. if length of returned set is greater than 0, child element with class dropdown exists:

```
 $(".toggle-nav").hover(function() {
   console.log($(this).find(".dropdown").length > 0);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use find:

```
$(".toggle-nav").hover(function() {
            console.log($(this).find(".dropdown").length);
        });
```

and then you can check with if statement if `length` is greater than 0 the class exists inside `toggle-nav`

Comment: `size()` is deprecated in 1.8 in the favor of `.length` property

Comment: find("dropdown") != find(".dropdown")

Comment: @Satpal so what is the recommend one?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is pointing to only hovered element and hasClass check existance of class on $(this).
So you have to use `$("ul",this).hasClass("dropdown")` instead of `$(this).hasClass("dropdown")` for check in child element.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggle-nav").hover(function() {
            console.log($("ul",this).hasClass("dropdown"));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="toggle-nav">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Add User</a></li>
        <li><a href="#>">User List</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="toggle-nav">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Add Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#>">Admin List</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="toggle-nav1"><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
</ul>
```